# mysql redirect query to view by select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have very big `mysql` table that contains date and data.
I created a `view` that holds only last 3 months of data to allow fast reading for my real time modules. 
Currently, my software reads from the big data table.

I need to know if there is any way that mysql server will 'read' my query
and if the select query date condition is less the 3 months, mysql will redirect the select to the view.

I have searched for a solution like `triggers`, but triggers is not for `select` query.

Comment: use stored procedure instaed of query